# Bootstrap 3.1.1 with iOS Emulator

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my site I used Bootstrap 3.0.2. All is working pretty great both on desktop and in my iOS emulator, where I test it for iPhone users.

However, when I tried to changed to Bootstrap 3.1.1, I can't seem to click on anything in my Web App (not links, not buttons, etc.). The site with 3.1.1 works pretty good on my desktop (with safari).

Any thoughts on why this happens?

**Update:**

Did a little debugging, and the problem seems to be with this line I use: 
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();

This is a hack I use to clear a modal that .modal('hide') didn't take care of for some reason. Can anyone think of why this makes the iOS stop responding to clicks?

Thanks

Comment: Can you send us a link to your site? I have used 3.1.1 for several websites already and works fine in my iOS simulator, so there has to be something else causing as issue

Comment: Maybe it's the version of the iOS? The iOS I'm using is pretty old, any chance it was not tested on versions before 7?
And my site is still not in production…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, iOS has a problem with "modal fade", so I just changed it to "modal".

This is probably not effecting bootstrap before 3.0.3, but when I changed it, the remove probably made the touch disabled somehow.

Works now.